# probabilistic loss

Tags: statistics

I have to calculate probability that losses will be $ 160,000 or below, with the following data
Annual Cost of losses   probability
 16,000                0.15
 32,000                0.3
 80,000                0.25
 160,000               0.15
 320,000               0.08
 800,000               0.05
 1,600,000             0.02

I have summed up the probabilities till they add upto 160,000 which is 0.7%(first three probabilities) but I am still unsure about the answer

Comment: Yeah, looks alright.

Comment: but wouldn't one probability cancel the affect of other.. I mean if loss of range $0 - 16000$ is 0.15 .. then wouldn't it mean if this happens others wont?

Comment: by that logic shouldn't I sum upto first 4 probabilities

Comment: How can I calculate $ expected loss per year ? ( buildup on the previous question )..

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is right, but the wording says 160000 **or below** so you need to add up $$0.15 + 0.3 + 0.25 + 0.15 = 0.85$$ to get a probability of 85%.

Comment: How can I calculate $ expected loss per year ? ( buildup on the previous question )..

Comment: By expected loss, they mean the average. You have a 15% probability of losing 16000, a 30% probability of losing 32000, etc. There's a formula for computing the mean as a weighted sum of this data.

Comment: can you please share the formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case

Comment: so the answer would simply be a sumproduct of all maximum losses that can happen against their probabilities... which in this case turn out to be 153600$

Comment: too tired to check your math, but your verbal description looks right.